# How do I get admin rights on MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I am in a bit of a situation and I am hoping someone might have the answer.

I have 'ready only' access to a MySQL remote database however the person who had full admin rights (and who set it up initially) has now passed away.

I now need to have access as I will be taking over a proportion of his role - I have the host url, port number as well as my own login details which are set as 'read only' so when I try to add a new user access is denied.

How do I get admin rights to this database?

Comment: If you have hosting login details and access to a control panel (like directadmin), you can reset the password there probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need ssh access in your server and root user password on your system to sun `sudo` commands in your terminal.

After you log in in ssh server run following commands:

**Stop MySql Service**:

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

> **Note:** You may come across error while runing above command and try these. `sudo systemctl stop mysqld` or `sudo service stop mysqld` depending which system you are using. Main purpose is to stop mysql service.

**Start MySQL without a password:**

`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

**Login as root without password:**

`mysql -u root`

**Then give your user admin privileges:**

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.table_name TO 'your_user'@'host'`

> Also you can change root user password by running these commands:
>
> ```
> use mysql;
> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where > > User='root';
> flush privileges;
> quit
> ```

Hope this helps.